# Android Google Maps with a map marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I wanna know if there is a way to make a map marker on the Google Maps (Android). Iam not talking about the tradicional marker, but a marker that can be used in parts of the map, like this red one: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=google+maps+mancha&rlz=1C1HLDY_pt-BRBR706BR706&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK1b-hlOrOAhULiZAKHT0vDdIQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=69yNhtI-G1quPM%3A . Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for. Thanks u a lot.